# dict.keys()[0] on Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, dictview

I have this sentence:

```
def Ciudad(prob):
    numero = random.random()
    ciudad = prob.keys()[0]
    for i in prob.keys():
        if(numero > prob[i]):
            if(prob[i] > prob[ciudad]):
                ciudad = i
        else:
            if(prob[i] > prob[ciudad]):
                ciudad = i

    return ciudad
```

But when I call it this error pops:

```
TypeError: 'dict_keys' object does not support indexing
```

is it a version problem? I'm using Python 3.3.2

Comment: What is this function supposed to achieve? Your random number has *no* influence on the outcome, you are basically picking the one key for which the value is the maximum.

Answer (score 112, accepted):

`dict.keys()` is a dictionary view. Just use `list()` directly on the dictionary instead if you need a list of keys, item 0 will be the first key in the (arbitrary) dictionary order:

```
list(prob)[0]
```

or better still just use:

```
next(iter(dict))
```

Either method works in both Python 2 *and* 3 and the `next()` option is certainly more efficient for Python 2 than using `dict.keys()`. Note however that dictionaries have *no* set order and you will *not* know what key will be listed first.

It looks as if you are trying to find the *maximum* key instead, use `max()` with `dict.get`:

```
def Ciudad(prob):
    return max(prob, key=prob.get)
```

The function result is certainly going to be the same for any given `prob` dictionary, as your code doesn't differ in codepaths between the random number comparison branches of the `if` statement.

Answer (score 15):

In Python 3.x, [`dict.keys()`](http://docs.python.org/3.1/library/stdtypes.html#dict.keys) does not return a list, it returns an iterable (specifically, [a dictionary view](http://docs.python.org/3.1/library/stdtypes.html#dictionary-view-objects)). It is worth noting that `dict` itself is also an iterable of the keys.

If you want to obtain the first key, use `next(iter(dict))` instead. (Note that before Python 3.6 dictionaries were unordered, so the 'first' element was an arbitrary one. Since 3.6 it will be based on insertion order. If you need that behaviour in older versions or with cross-version compatibility, you can use [`collections.OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict)).

This works quite simply: we take the iterable from the dictionary view with `iter()`, then use `next()` to advance it by one and get the first key.

If you need to iterate over the keys—then there is definitely no need to construct a list:

```
for key in dict:
    ...
```

These are all advantageous when compared to using `list()` as it means a list isn't constructed - making it faster and more memory efficient (hence why the default behaviour of `keys()` was changed in 3.x). Even in Python 2.x you would be better off doing `next(iter(dict.iterkeys())`.

Note all these things apply to `dict.values()` and `dict.items()` as well.

Comment: @MartijnPieters `next()` requires an iterator, not an iterable. `next(iter(dict))` is a little more concise though.

Comment: Ah, yes, figured that out just now too.

Comment: note as of python 3.6, dictionaries are ordered by default, I know this post was likely from before, but might be worth updating this

Comment: @SBFRF Indeed, I've changed the note about what the "first" element means to make that distinction clear. It doesn't change the core of the question though, the same method is still optimal, just with a more specific result.

Comment: @GarethLatty  Agreed

Answer (score 1):

I've had success turning the iterables taken from a dictionary into a list.
So, for dic.keys(), dic.values(), and dic.items(), in Python3.6, you can:

```
dic = {'a':3, 'b':2, 'c':3}
print(dic)

dictkeys = dic.keys() # or values/items
print(dictkeys)

keylist = []
keylist.extend(iter(dictkeys)) # my big revelation
print('keylist', keylist)
```